# logic behind wp autosave

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp-2.3, autosave

I've read that changes you make in Wordpress are automatically saved every 2 minutes; and that there is only one autosave for each post or page, and each new autosave overwrites the previous autosave in the database.

Now, I'm trying to replicate this functionality with Cake and Cake doesn't seem to have this built-in yet so I want to know how this is done first. I've googled this topic a lot but the logic behind is not discussed.. Question: Once Wordpress autosaves, will it save the id of the first saved data then just do sql update each time another autosave runs? And another update to same data row when published? Is this how Wordpress works its autosave? If so, is it using cookie/session only on each update?

Comment: The versioning in Wordpress is done by saving a new entry in the database and flag it as draft. Please have a look at the articles table in the Database of a wordpress installation. Depending on the edits of a single article there might be many versions in the database available, but only one is active...